# Restart Challenges?

Tags: discussion, meta

It's back to school time, more or less, in the US, so a lot of us have September Energy!  (This is always the *real* new year's for me, and time for resolutions I can actually follow)

So: **Tag Challenges**?

Or any other sort of challenge that may be useful for us, especially as we are no longer Beta?

This may be relevant and perhaps needs to be revisited:
[If we could have a custom design, what elements are most important?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/if-we-could-have-a-custom-design-what-elements-are-most-important)

Related - does the tag "Site Promotion" mean promoting our site just like one would promo any other service or event, or is it about promotion *out of Beta?*

Comment: Good morning!  I would love to see what people are up for.  Thanks for starting this.  [meta-tag:site-promotion] is for posts that talk about (or are about) promoting the existence of our site and promoting quality posts, etc.

Comment: Do keep in mind that, for some of us, including me, this *is* the real new year so the second half of Sept and most of Oct (it varies year to year) will be pretty busy.  Don't let this stop you though. :-)

Comment: I miss teaching!  I always had my syllabus and first month of things set by mid August, *but* I couldn't complete my course calendar until I had seen the students once. Not sure why, but if I tried earlier, dates would always get weird.

Comment: I added a bit of description to the tag [meta-tag:site-promotion] wiki so that it's now documented. If you feel like it should be something entirely different or just want to discuss how it's used right now it would be better to start a new discussion so that it's easier to find later and that each discussion on meta is focused on exactly one thing instead of two. @Cyn If you want to link to a tag on meta with magic links you need to write `[meta-tag:site-promotion]`. Otherwise it will link to the main site if you just write `[tag:site-promotion]`.

Comment: @Secespitus ha ha thanks.  Forgot about the meta addition to tag.  Note to all that [meta-tag:graduation] is the tag for promoting us out of beta (or discussing of that *past* event).

Comment: The wiki looks good, thanks!

Comment: Are we doing the challenges? Or was nothing decided from this conversation?

Comment: I think everyone wanted to use their back-to-school energy for actual back-to-school work.    I was thinking today how I miss the ego-boost of incentivized participation here, though.  I know how bad I can be with follow through, so we'll need someone else to actually "run" the thing.

Comment: @April What would be required to "run" the thing? How was in done in the past?

Comment: With this moderator issue (see "SE Has Removed A Moderator") , I'm not sure how much I want to participate in growth-oriented challenges on any stack-exchange site.   But I think someone would just announce the challenge, make a community wiki type answer for people to list entries, stuff like that?  Maybe browse the archives in this meta for examples.